# Display Sharepoint MultipleLinesOfText field in Report Builder

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to create a report in Report Builder 3.0

The datasource is a Sharepoint List that has two "Multiple Lines of Text" (MLT) fields. When I run the report, only the most recent entry is displayed, but I want to show all the entries for the MLT columns.

How can I create a report query that will allow me to see / display all the entries in my MLT columns?

I've seen some information about using WVDP but that is not applicable to a ReportBuilder report.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you build the XML query using the Query Designer in Report Builder? Also, do you have versioning turned on for the list?

Comment: Yes. I used the ReportBuilder query tool.
Yes. We have versioning turned on.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the versioning. Do you need that for some reason?

Comment: Yes. We need a record of date-time/ modified-by for entries made in that field.

Any suggestions for getting all the entries from that field?  Being Sharepoint newbie, I've not had to deal with this before and I'm stumped.

Comment: You can't query previous versions of the values this way. You would have to directly access the raw data in the SharePoint database. You can export the values, but that's not very helpful from a reporting perspective.